# Scraping for a specific title using Nokogiri in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, screen-scraping

I'm currently practicing web scraping using the NYT Best Sellers website. I want to get the title of the #1 book on the list and found the HTML element:

```
<div class="book-body">
  <p class="freshness">12 weeks on the list</p>
  <h3 class="title" itemprop="name">CRAZY RICH ASIANS</h3>
  <p class="author" itemprop="author">by Kevin Kwan</p>
  <p itemprop="description" class="description">A New Yorker gets a surprise when she spends the summer with her boyfriend in Singapore.</p>
</div>
```

I'm using the following code to grab the specific text:

```
doc.css(".title").text
```

However, it returns the titles of every book on the list. How would I go about getting just the specific book title, "CRAZY RICH ASIANS"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the return from `doc.css(".title")` you will see it is a collection of all the titles. As `Nokogiri::XML::Element` Objects

CSS to my knowledge does not have a selector for targeting the first element of a given class. (Someone may certainly correct me if I am wrong) but to get just the first element from a `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet` is still very simple as it acts like an `Array` in many cases. For Example:

```
doc.css(".title")[0].text
```

You could also use xpath to select just the first one (since XPath does support index based selection) like so:

```
doc.xpath(doc.xpath("(//h3[@class='title'])[1]").text
```

**Please Note:**

- Ruby indexes start at 0 as in the first example;
- XPath indexes start at 1 as in the second example.

Comment: You can select the first element of a class with `.title:first-of-type`

Comment: @josephcho from my understanding and basic testing that is not how that selector works. It is a parent child selector so you will get the first-of-type .title from every div `book-body:first-of-type > .title` might work but I don't know the exact context of the page so I can't guarantee this either

Comment: @engineersmnky - doc.css(".title")[0].text worked like a charm. Looking at the NodeSet like an array really helps me understand this better.

Comment: @Sharq glad it helped please feel free to mark this as correct in that case